# SQL удаление строк в соответствии содержимым из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть отдельная таблица "regs":

```
SELECT sip, ua FROM regs;
```

Получается:

```
                          sip          |                ua
---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
 sip:test1                             | Panasonic 111111111111
 sip:test1                             | Yealink 222222222222
 sip:test2                             | Yealink 222222222222
```

Есть отдельная таблица "wa":

```
SELECT sip, mac FROM wa;
```

Получается:

```
                           sip                           |     mac
---------------------------------------------------------+--------------
 sip:test1                                               | 111111111111
 sip:test1                                               | 222222222222
 sip:test2                                               | 222222222222
 sip:test3                                               | 333333333333
 sip:test4                                               | 444444444444
```

Необходимо удалить из таблицы "wa" строки, которых нет в таблице "regs"
по условию:  `wa.sip=regs.sip, regs.ua содержит wa.sip`

Я пошел следующим путем:

- Написал тестовый sql запрос:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT(wa.sip), wa.mac FROM wa LEFT JOIN regs ON wa.sip = regs.sip
  ```

  and regs.ua LIKE CONCAT ('%',wa.mac,'%') WHERE regs IS NULL;
- Получил те данные, которые необходимо удалить из таблицы "wa":

  ```
                             sip                           |     mac
  ---------------------------------------------------------+--------------
   sip:test3                                               | 333333333333
   sip:test4                                               | 444444444444
  ```
- Попробовал удалить вот так:

  ```
    DELETE FROM wa WHERE wa.sip IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT( wa.sip) FROM wa LEFT JOIN regs ON wa.sip = regs.sip and regs.ua LIKE CONCAT ('%',wa.mac,'%') WHERE regs IS NULL)
      and wa.mac IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT (wa.mac) FROM wa LEFT JOIN regs ON wa.sip = regs.sip and regs.ua LIKE CONCAT ('%',wa.mac,'%') WHERE regs IS NULL);
  ```

Но к сожалению, такой запрос удаляет лишние данные из таблицы "wa":

```
 sip:test1                      | 222222222222
```

Помогите составить sql запрос, чтобы удалить из таблицы "wa" все строки, которые совпадают с моим тестовым SELECT'ом по двум параметрам sip и mac.

А может изначально нужно было пойти по другому пути?

Comment: а ситуации никак не избежать если использовать внешний ключ к примеру?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вы излишне намудрили с запросом.

```
DELETE FROM wa WHERE wa.sip NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT regs.sip FROM regs
)
```

Comment: В подзапросе должно быть условие `wa.sip=regs.sip, regs.ua содержит wa.sip` второй части условия в ответе нет

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE wa.*
FROM wa
LEFT JOIN regs  ON wa.sip=regs.sip 
               AND wa.mac = SUBSTRING_INDEX(regs.ua, ' ', -1)
WHERE regs.sip IS NULL
```

Вместо SUBSTRING_INDEX в условии связывания можно и чего попроще использовать - вплоть до тупого

```
AND LOCATE(wa.mac, regs.ua)
```

Ну или

```
DELETE 
FROM wa
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM regs   
                   WHERE wa.sip=regs.sip 
                         AND wa.mac = SUBSTRING_INDEX(regs.ua, ' ', -1)
                  )
```

Comment: DELETE wa.*
 FROM wa
 LEFT JOIN regs  ON wa.sip=regs.sip
                AND wa.mac = SUBSTRING_INDEX(regs.ua, ' ', -1)
 WHERE regs.sip IS NULL;
ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "wa")
LINE 1: DELETE wa.*

Comment: @SergeyRakov Да, на автомате рисовал ответ для MySQL, сорри. А что со второй версией? ну если заменить SUBSTRING_INDEX на аналог из постгресса...

Comment: Заменил функцию для PostgreSql, работает. Спасибо.
DELETE 
FROM wa
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM regs   
                    WHERE wa.sip=regs.sip -- index scan
                      AND STRPOS(regs.ua, wa.mac) > 0 -- filter
                  )